# Clarification on how to store user input and point system for javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, store

So I'm a bit new to coding and just needed direction, not necessarily doing it for me, but some steering.

I need to make a personality quiz that takes user choices and based on their choices gives them a certain outcome out of 4 choices at the end.

I know to create an array with questions and answers, but I'm not exactly clear what the next step is to set up a system to store user input.

Do I use another array to store the data?
Does that array have to refer to the buttons I make or the array earlier?

I'm not even sure if that's the right steps, I just need some clarification to the next step I should take after I create an array of my questions and answers.

Comment: If the quiz must be done in a single session then arrays are probably the best way to go. If the quiz can be done over multiple sessions then cookies would be best as to pickup the previously answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using another array should be fine, I would create the array for answers with empty strings right at the beginning. You already know the length of both the questions and answers arrays should be the same. So something along the lines of:

```
var answersArray = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < questionsArray.length; i++) {
  answersArray[i] = '';
}
```

After that you can use your buttons to fill the answersArray depending on the index that they belong. No matter the order in which the user answers the quiz, or if they don't fill all the answers. This way it will be easy for you to process the result in any way you need. All you need is an if statement that checks for the length:

```
if (answersArray[i].length > 0) {
  // do something ...
}
```

Note that this is a very simple approach that does not take into account saving the data in any way (cookies, localstorage or database).